# Finding a variable in a list with other stored variables from a class

Tags: python, list, class

I want to search a list for a Title, then remove the Title along with the Author and Rating stored with it.

```
myBooks = []

class = Class
title = input("title")
author = input("author")
rating = input("rating")

myBook = Class
myBooks.append(myBook)
```

I then want a method that will search the list for a title and if the title exists remove the title and the author and rating given to that title.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: some code will be helpful.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Then why not figure it out **before** posting?!

Comment: Have tried to clear it up and add a brief summary of the code.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It's not very obvious what you're after, but I threw this together quickly. Using titles as the unique keys is a bad idea so I'd recommend change it, this is just a starting point to go from :)

```
class BookClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def add(self, title, author, rating):
        self.kwargs[title] = (author, rating)

    def remove(self, title):
        return self.kwargs.pop(title)

    #Example of how you'd go about getting all the authors or whatever
    def authors(self):
        for title in self.kwargs:
            print self.kwargs[title][0]
```

To add to it using your code:

```
title = input("title")
author = input("author")
rating = input("rating")

myBooks = BookClass()
myBooks.add(title, author, rating)
```

The to search the list and remove the book

```
title = input("title")
author, rating = myBooks.remove(title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not 100% clear that you wanted functionality to first add a book to your list, but I assumed this was the case.

This doesn't handle the situation where two books have the same title, in this case maybe you'd want something more unique like ISBN to be the key.

Use a `dict` to store your books and make it keyed by `title`.

```
# myBooks dict indexed by book title
myBooks = {}

class BookNotFoundException(Exception):
    pass

def addbook(title, author, rating):
    ''' adds a book '''
    myBooks[title] = {'author':author, 'rating':rating}

def removebook(title):
    ''' removes a book otherwise throws an exception '''
    if title in myBooks:
        del myBooks[title]
    else:
        raise BookNotFoundException('Book %s not found in list' % title)

# input the params
title = input("title")
author = input("author")
rating = input("rating")

## call add book
addbook(title, author, rating)

## print the dict to see what you have
print(myBooks)

# enter item to remove
toremove = input('enter title of book to remove: ')

try:
    # try to remove book
    removebook(toremove)
    print('removed ok')
except BookNotFoundException as e:
    print('didnt remove ok')

# convince yourself its empty now
print(myBooks)
```